# Jquery function not defined

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with loading this code. I am sure its something to do with noConflict but i cant seem to get it right.

```
$(document).ready(
   function spouseName() {
      if ($('#maritalstatus').val() == 'married') {
         $('#spousename').attr("disabled", false);
      } else {
         $('#spousename').val('');
         $('#spousename').attr("disabled", true);
      }
   }
);
```

by the way, it works on IE but not FF

Comment: there is textbox that should not be disabled but it still remains so and firebug says spouseName not defined.

Comment: Got the problem solved with another SO question
function spouseName { 
    $(document).ready(
   //Rest of the jquery function
    ):
}
Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

thanks for the info and answers, it seems this thread helped

[Function not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773356/function-not-defined)

firefox does not recognize the function name when it inside the jquery document.ready function. what i did was wrap it inside although it seems unconventional. I just removed the document ready and it works perfectly. seems chrome and FF dont recognize function names within this?

```
function spouseName() {
  if ($('#maritalstatus').val() == 'married') {
     $('#spousename').attr("disabled", false);
  } 
  else {
     $('#spousename').val('');
     $('#spousename').attr("disabled", true);
  }
```

}

Comment: When using jQuery, it's not as vital to call a function inline from an element, like 'onChange'. 

Instead, jQuery allows you to assign a function to an element type. For instance, `$('select').on('change', function(){...});` would serve the purpose of an inline 'onChange' function call.

Answer (score 4):

The "jQuery not defined" error happens if you have not included jQuery or may imported beneath your JavaScript.

It should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjsfile.js"> </script>
```

`myjsfile.js` should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    every function inside this
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the function() after ready()

should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   function spouseName() { // your code }
   function anotherFunction() { }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. Are you using [`$.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)? If so there is an example in the documentation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        if ($('#maritalstatus').val() == 'married') {
            $('#spousename').attr("disabled", false);
        }
        else {
            $('#spousename').val('');
            $('#spousename').attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });

    // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

But in all cases make sure that you have properly referenced the jquery script itself before attempting to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, jQuery can't find a function because of **scope** issues. You could define the function as below and important subject is to set the function scope to global:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
      function sample() { console.log('blah blah'); } 
      window.sample = sample; //export function sample to the globals.
})
```

or shorter form as below:

```
(function($) { 
      function sample() { console.log('blah blah'); } 
      window.sample = sample; //export function sample to the globals.
})(jQuery)
```

Hope this help.